# WordPress update_user_meta does not post radio button values

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, radio-button

I have been trying to make a custom form located on a separate page in my WordPress website. I ended up making a plugin that generates the form html and should post entered data in wp_usermeta. There are three radio button options, one of which is "other", that once clicked makes a textbox visible for alternative input.

The issue I have is that radio button values are not posted to wp_usermeta, only textbox input is (if entered).

Here is the html snippet for the form:

```
<form name="forming_the_team" method="POST" action="">
    <div id="about">
         A. Tell us about the team. <br/>
         <input type="radio" name="team" value="club" onclick="otherCheck()" id="club"/>Club<br/>
         <input type="radio" name="team" value="class" onclick="otherCheck()" id="class"/>Class<br/>
         <input type="radio" name="team" value="other" id="other-radio" onclick="otherCheck()"/>Other</br>
         <input type="text" name="team2" id="other-box"/><br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
</form>
```

otherCheck() onclick attribute is a javascript function that makes a text box visible if "other" radio button is checked.

Here is one of the things I tried (among others) to update wp_usermeta:

```
 <?php function handleDB() {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        if(document.getElementById('club').checked) {
              <?php update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', $_POST['team']);?>
        }
        if(document.getElementById('class').checked) {
              <?php update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', $_POST['team']);?>
        } 
        if(document.getElementById('other-radio').checked)  {
              <?php update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', $_POST['team2']);?>
        }

        </script>

        <?php     
}?>
```

I call handleDB() from the same page via shortcode:

```
function shortcodeDB() {
    ob_start();
    displayHTML();
    handleDB();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('form_handle','shortcodeDB');
```

To summarize, text input gets posted successfully, while radio button values post NULL. What can I do to post radio button values as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix client side code (javascript) and server side code (PHP) in the that way. The PHP is going to run no matter what in what you have posted. Here is a solution that should work using only PHP.

```
<?php function handleDB() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( 'other' == $_POST['team'] ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', $_POST['team2']);    
    }else{
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', $_POST['team']);
    }
}
?>
```

If this doesn't work comment below and I will troubleshoot further but this should do the trick.